# How to project the vector b onto the subspace x+y=0

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The question asks to project the vector $b=(2, 3, 4, 1)$ into the subspace $x+y=0$. What is the distance? I understand that the projection onto the subspace is calculated through the formula $p=A((A^{T}A)^{-1}A^{T})b$. The distance would then be the magnitude of the vector $p-b$. The problem I'm having though is finding what this matrix $A$
is. What I do know is that $b$ has four components so $A$ must have four rows. In lecture, the professor showed the class that $A$ could possibly be $$A=\begin{bmatrix} -1 &0 &0 \\ 1& 0 &0 \\ 0& 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$. His reasoning for the 1 and the -1 in the first column was that they satisfy $x+y=0$. However, if the first row corresponds to x and the second row corresponds to y, what do the other two rows correspond to? Are $x$ & $y$ even referring to row vectors in the matrix $A$?

Comment: The columns of $A$ should be vectors which span the subspace you're projecting onto.

Answer (score 0):

it is easier to project the vector $b$ onto the line $(1,1,0,0)^T$ first. choose $k$ so that $(2,3,4,1) - k(1,1,0,0)$ is orthogonal to $(1,1,0,0)$ gives $$2-k + 3 - k= 0 \implies k = 5/2$$ and so the projection onto the plane $x + y = 0$ is $$(-1/2, 1/2, 4, 1)^T. $$

Comment: This answers the question in the title but not the one in the body.